# How to trigger the Github collaboration mechanism when using two accounts on same computer?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have two Github accounts, gh1 and gh2.

Both accounts have two repositories called A and B.

The A repo for gh1 allows gh2 to collaborate, but its B repo has no collaborators.
The A repo for gh2 allows gh1 to collaborate, but its B repo has no collaborators.

I use a bash shell on a Windows 10 PC.

**My objectives are (from the bash command line) to**

- be able to push commits as user gh1 to all of gh1's repos, as well as gh2's A repo but not gh2's B repo.
- be able to push commits as user gh2 to all of gh2's repos, as well as gh1's A repo but not gh1's B repo.

**I have done the following so far**

- There were already existing id_rsa and id_rsa.pub keys in my ~/.ssh directory. The id_rsa key was already added to the ssh-agent. I added the public key to the gh1 account.
- Created new keys id_ed25519_gh2 and id_ed25519_gh2.pub. Added id_ed25519_gh2 to the ssh-agent. Added its public counterpart to the gh2 account.
- Created ~/.ssh/config as follows:

```
    #Default GitHub host is for gh1 account
    Host github.com
      HostName github.com
      User git
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      
    #GitHub host for gh2 account
    Host github.com-gh2
      HostName github.com
      User git
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_gh2
```

- Already created Github repositories as described above.
- Created local directories gh1A, gh1B, gh2A, gh2B.
  In each directory, ran `git init` to create corresponding local repo.
- Added remote to each local repo as follows:

  - For gh1A, executed `git remote add origin git@github.com:gh1/A.git`
  - For gh1B, executed `git remote add origin git@github.com:gh1/B.git`
  - For gh2A, executed `git remote add origin git@github.com-gh2:gh2/A.git`
  - For gh2B, executed `git remote add origin git@github.com-gh2:gh2/B.git`
- Executed the following command:

  - `alias gh2="git -c user.name=gh2 user.email=gh2@gmail.com"`

  The global config defines `user.name=gh1` and `user.email=gh1@gmail.com`.
- In each directory, created new commits as follows:

  - `git commit -m "Create m1"`
  - `gh2 commit -m "Create m2"`

**The Problem (at least with respect to my objectives)**

I can push to every repo, regardless of "who I am". The collaboration mechanism does not get honored.

**What does work**

The correct user appears in the Github repos. So, a commit by gh1 shows "gh1" in Github. A commit by gh2 shows "gh2" in GitHub. I'm fairly sure that this is unrelated to any of my SSH setup and is, rather, solely due to which user.name and user.email are being used by the 'git commit' command.

**Questions**

1. How do I "pretend to be gh1" or "pretend to be gh2" when pushing?
2. How can I prevent pushes to gh1's B repo that are made by gh2 from being accepted?
3. How can I prevent pushes to gh2's B repo that are made by gh1 from being accepted?
4. Should I be using 'IdentitiesOnly yes' for each host in the config file?